# Пропала капча в поле проверки на ru.stackoverflow

Tags: дефект, поддержка, вопросы, recaptcha

SO не оставил мне шансов задать вопрос.

[image: капча]

AdBlock отключен. SO не только считает меня роботом, так еще и не дает шанса показать, что я человек. Что мне делать?

P.S. Может быть я на самом деле робот, который не может пройти капчу. Самый эффективный способ - спросить у людей, как это делается.

Comment: Там рекаптча стоит, может она сбоит. Ща я попробую....

Comment: У меня всё нормально: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9oiM.jpg

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev отгадка оказалась проста - РКПозор - написал ответ

Answer (score 0):

Решение - использовать ВПН. РосКомНадзор так и не прекратил блокировки ip пулов(хотя писали, что больше так не будут), поэтому некоторые сервисы некоторых корпораций могут не работать без ВПН.

Comment: *так и не прекратил блокировки ip пулов* — возможно, это провайдер «тормозит». проверьте адрес здесь: http://eais.rkn.gov.ru/